# wget returns StatusCode 200 but can't find the file

Tags: powershell, wget

I'm trying to download the Caltech-101 dataset, and to do that I used `wget http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/101_ObjectCategories.tar.gz` in Powershell. It says "Reading web response" for some time as the number of bytes received goes up, and then I get the following:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {31, 139, 8, 8...}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    x-amz-id-2: JpVe7IUO7M6fWpV33hpaYzsvayEwogYD7jou1naeQmIczvQ0kVPScRPGxgbvHSEWbJP123U4WAc=
                    x-amz-request-id: BC71FD061F396BA1
                    x-amz-version-id: null
                    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
                    C...
Headers           : {[x-amz-id-2, JpVe7IUO7M6fWpV33hpaYzsvayEwogYD7jou1naeQmIczvQ0kVPScRPGxgbvHSEWbJP123U4WAc=],
                    [x-amz-request-id, BC71FD061F396BA1], [x-amz-version-id, null], [Keep-Alive, timeout=5,
                    max=100]...}
RawContentLength  : 131740031
```

The file isn't stored in the folder I run the command from, and when I try `tar -zxvf 101_ObjectCat
egories.tar.gz` I get a failed to open error. Is wget actually downloading anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wget is an alias for powershell "Invoke-Webrequest" so you can lookup the MS docs on that to get a better understanding of how it works.

Essentially it is getting the file into the powershell session and not just downloading it to a local location.

What you want to do is something like this

```
$uri="http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/101_ObjectCategories.tar.gz"
$saveFolder="$($env:USERPROFILE)\Documents\"
$filename=(split-path $uri -Leaf)
$saveFile="$($saveFolder)$($filename)"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -OutFile $saveFile
```